# un efecto javascript del scroll solo me afecta a una pagina en vez de a todas

Tags: javascript, html, css

Mi problema es el siguiente, he programado un pequeño script para que el header de una pagina se suba unos cuantos pixeles cuando se hace scroll hacia abajo. mi problema es que solo se me aplica en la pagina de la tienda de mi pagina web y en el resto no funciona, es extraño pues el js esta referenciado en todas las paginas pero solo en esa me hace caso.

Por aqui dejo el codigo:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const scrollPX = window.scrollY;
    const cabecera = document.querySelector('header');
    const carrito = document.querySelector('#boton-carrito');

    console.log(scrollPX);
    if(scrollPX >= 35) {
        cabecera.style.top = '-35px';
    }
    else if(scrollPX >= 26.25) {
        cabecera.style.top = '-26.25px';
    }
    else if(scrollPX >= 17.5) {
        cabecera.style.top = '-17.5px'
    }
    else if(scrollPX >= 8.75) {
        cabecera.style.top = '-8.75px'
    }
    else {
        cabecera.style.top = '0px';
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Al ejecutar el método Scroll estas haciendo referencia a 2 elementos:

Cabecera = "header"
Carrito = #boton-carrito

Tienes que identificar que en las otras paginas estos elementos tengas exactamente los mismos atributos.

La clase 'header' y el id #boton-carrito

Además de agregarles el script del archivo.js

Comment: ocurria un error por otra parte del codigo que era erronea pero gracias por contestar igualmente